# DLL error while adding to GAC

Tags: vb.net

My problem is this - I have developed an application in SharePoint v2010, which generates pdf with `hiQPdf bookstore`.

My problem is that I can't add it to GAC. While Trying to add I receive the following error:

`Error in the implementation step Add Solution Can not load file or assembly 'C: \ Windows \ Temp \ solution-2ece0435-c548-483f-A511-f7754a584b97 \ HiQPdf.dll' or one of its dependencies. this assembly was created with a more recent time of execution runtime is currently loaded and will not load`

Please ask if need additional info

Comment: Are you sure this is happens when you add to GAC and not when you running the application?

Comment: @T.S. this happens when implementing the solution, as shown in the following image http://i.imgur.com/8Ln7Ys4.png

Comment: You are using the wrong version of Gacutil.exe, it is too old.  If you don't tell us what you used and don't mention your VS version then it gets hard to help you.

Comment: Search this website for `This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded` - this is common

Comment: Why did you rollback my last revision? I posted correct error in English instead of your incorrect translation